# Jquery UI Slider change value of slider when changed in input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

```js
$("#storlekslider").slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 0,
  max: 1500,
  value: 0,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#storlek_testet").val(ui.value);
    $(ui.value).val($('#storlek_testet').val());
  }
});
// $( "#storlek_testet" ).val( $( "#storlekslider" ).slider( "value" ) );

$("#storlek_testet").change(function() {
  $("#storlekslider").slider("value", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="storlekslider"></div>
<input type="text" name="storlek" id="storlek_testet" value="500" />
```

Heres a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4gqJ/)

im trying to get the slider to jump to the correct position when I change the value in the input field.
Iam using the [Jquery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You attach to the `change` event of your input like so:

```
$("#storlek_testet").change(function() {
    $("#storlekslider").slider("value", $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: $(this).val() can be used instead of the selector $("storlek_testet").val()

Comment: there is also `#` and `);` missing ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Change values from several inputs:

```
$("#input-1").change(function() {
    $("#slider").slider('values',0,$(this).val());
});
$("#input-2").change(function() {
    $("#slider").slider('values',1,$(this).val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brhuman/uvx6pdc1/

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#storlek_testet").keyup(function() {
    $("#storlekslider").slider("value" , $(this).val())
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8X4D/

Comment: how to implement it for wordpress plugin option panel

Comment: `change()` is preferable to `keyup()` if `input` is of type `number`, because `keyup()` won't apply changes when the field up/down buttons are used to change the input value.